# Git - README.md Disappeared

Tags: git, github, command

I had an error on Git "! [rejected] main -> main (fetch first)" so I typed the following commands.

```
$ git fetch origin main
$ git merge  main
$ git fetch origin main:tmp
$ git rebase tmp   // Didn't work
$ git push -f origin main
```

I'm pretty sure after I did this, README.md that I created was gone and asked me to make one.
I don't know why this is happening.
Did anyone went through the same?

Comment: You should be able to get back your `Readme` from the reflog for `origin/main` : `git reflog origin/main`

Comment: Note that command #1 (`git fetch origin main`) isn't *wrong* but it does not create a local `main`, so command #2 won't do anything useful at that point. Command #3 does create a local branch name `tmp` and the missing information is what "// Didn't work" *means*, i.e., what precisely went wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 (Optional). Promise yourself to not use `-f` / `--force` when unsure what to do.

Step 2. Recover lost work into a branch:

1. If there are files that are not committed, deal with them first (e.g. create a new branch and commit them there to not loose them, you can always merge them later)
2. `git checkout main`
3. `git reflog`
4. Find the entry that you think should have the lost file
5. `git checkout commit_id` (e.g. b60e80b)
6. `git switch -c my_recovery_branch`
   Now you have your lost work in branch, that's a good spot to relax.

Step 3. Make main good

If `main` looks OK and only your one file is missing then just get it from `my_recovery_branch` and move on.

If `main` has lost other work you'd need to rewind it to the last known good state.

If there is a WebUI for your git repo (Azure DevOps, BitBucket, GitLab, GitHub, etc.) check if you can rewind from there.

If you need to do this in the command line, here's one way:

1. `git checkout main`
2. `git checkout -b main_backup`
3. `git reflog`
4. Find the last good commit
5. `git reset commit_id --hard`
6. `git push --force`

I think the best option would be to reset main to a commit