# Github files are deleting automatically from the repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-bash

**I am new to the GitHub**

so, I created a repository and started pushing some CPP code files, then after two or three days I again checked my folders(inside the repo) and found that each folder rarely has one file,but I pushed more than 6 files into each folder (amount of folders 5), is there any solution for this problem?

I pushed all the files using `git push -f origin main` , is this creating the problem, or  something else please help? and how do I retrieve those files?

Comment: It is hard to say what has happened without seeing `git log --all` output or `gitk --all` screenshot. There is a command `git reflog` that keeps history of all commits you have created/checked out so if something has been inadvertently deleted that's a potential place to recover from.

Comment: What's your GitHub repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stop using `-f` (`--force`) flag until you really must and know what you're doing:

   1. In most cases it means that something went wrong
   2. If you're using it often and regularly it means that the workflow is flawed
   3. It often leads to trouble
2. In your repo in github use the commits tab to try to find your missing files:
   [image]
3. If you cannot find your files in the history in GitHub, you can try with `git reflog` on you computer. You can find steps in, for example,  [Git - README.md Disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74297433/git-readme-md-disappeared/74298084#74298084).

Comment: thanks a lot,that commit and reflog helped